# Apply theme programmatically

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to apply a separate theme for each user role.  I know there is option to do this from the admin side, but I want to do this programmatically.
I found an option using global $custom_theme. I changed my code as

```
function mymodule_config_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
global $custom_theme;   
$custom_theme = 'bluemarine';
init_theme();
```

}

But it is not affecting the theme  .Is this required any modifications?

Pls help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's too late to change the theme at the point of preprocessing variables, you'll probably want to do this in [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6):

```
function mymodule_init() {
  global $custom_theme;   
  $custom_theme = 'bluemarine';
}
```

As far as I know there's no need to call `init_theme()` as Drupal will do this for you later on in the process, using the global `$custom_theme` to decide which theme to use.

Comment: i changed the condtion then the theme was applied but ut gives me a warning message  " warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'phptemplate_menu_local_tasks' was given in"

Comment: Navigate to this path : /admin/build/themes. Scroll to the bottom and click on 'Save Configuration', that should clear the cache and fix your problem.

Comment: Am sorry to disturb u. One more issue is there. The theme is not affecting the block page ie. admin/build/block

Answer (score 0):

The theme is already initialized when your `mymodule_config_preprocess_page()` is executed. once initialized, the theme cannot be re-initialized.

Looking at the [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module code, it changes the value of `$custom_theme` in `hook_init()`. That's probably the best hook to implement theme change in Drupal 6.

```
function mymodule_init() {
  global $custom_theme;   
  $custom_theme = 'bluemarine';
}
```